# Load records on XAMPP localhost

Tags: mysql, upload, xampp, localhost

As far as I understand using xampp for production isn't really a good idea.
 But I'm developing an e-commerce website for a store and while I do my job, it would be great if my client could start uploading on localhost to mysql, through  the form I made, to let them start populating the tables.

We're talking about thousands of records that then I would export and upload on the website once it's finished. 
Are there any contraindications about this workflow?

Comment: Feeding live data to an app that's still under development means you need to create (and test) migration scripts every time you change anything. And doing it in client's PC rather than an internet faced server means you need a plan for upgrades (either install a remote deskptop app or drive to client's office). It's also unlikely that proper backups will exist.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Table fields are already determined and won't change anytime soon. I see my client once a week, so I can update his code. Scripts may vary but at least he can start inserting data and let us continue our job on backend, security and frontend development. My main concern was about xampp mysql data export and import on phpmyadmin on the live server. It shouldn't create any issues even if records are thousands, right?